# Проблемма с include

Tags: html, python, django

Я делаю рандом 3 статей из базы данных и добавить их в шаблон и данные из этого шаблона передать в другой шаблон с помощью include (короче: есть 1 шаблон со статьями и я пытаюся добавить эти статьи в другой шаблон при помощи include) и у меня появилося ошибка

```
Traceback:

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  176.                 template = context.template.engine.get_template(template_name)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in get_template
  143.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in find_template
  129.         raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name, tried=tried)

The above exception (randomArticle/randoms.html) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  143.                 response = response.render()

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  63.             reraise(exc, self.backend)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in reraise
  84.     raise new from exc

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /news/
Exception Value: randomArticle/randoms.html
```

1 шаблон куда добовляються статьи

```
{% include 'randomArticle/randoms.html' %}
```

randoms.html

```
{% for object in object_list  %}


      <a href="/programms/{{object.id}}"> <h1> {{object.title}} </h1> </a>


{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

# Create your views here.
from .news.models import Articles


class RandomDetail(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'randomArticle/random.html'

class RandomsList(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'randomArticle/randoms.html'

    def RandomArticles(request):
        random_article = Articles.objects.order_by('?')[:3]
        return render(request, 'randomArticle/randoms.html', {'random_article': random_article , 'posts':posts})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', RandomsList.as_view(), name='articles_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', RandomDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),


    ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Неправильно шаблон подключаешь.

Comment: А как правильно ?

Comment: Я ж не знаю, какая структура проекта у тебя.

Comment: А я где находиться шаблон неправильно указал да ?